Can simulations be created in 3D models in AnyLogic？
I am a novice user of AnyLogic and after looking at some cases, I found that it seems that AnyLogic's simulation environment is created with 2D views first. However, I need to simulate crowd behavior in Unity, and the scene has already been created in FBX format as a 3D model. Can AnyLogic directly import 3D models in FBX format and simulate tasks such as crowd generation/target point creation, evacuation event generation, etc. in this 3D environment?
In fact, I converted FBX to .dae format and imported it into AnyLogic to create a 3D object, but it doesn't seem to display 3D objects like Unity in AnyLogic's editor? How should I display 3D objects and set up elements such as escalators, walls, and crowd generation points in AnyLogic editor?



AnyLogic is able to create 3D simulations in 3D objects, although the standard development environment looks 2D.
If you go into Help -> Example Models you will find one model called Pedestrian Elevator which should provide you with some basic functionality and you can inspect the code to learn how it is done - you can also view the model online at https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/4636a3bd-b9bb-47e0-9efa-7119e332109b?mode=SETTINGS
It is important to notice that AnyLogic focus right now is on the simulation and results, and thus the 3D capacities and rendering will not be as realistic as Unity. This is being worked for next versions and they had a very nice presentation on the last conference which can be seen at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=beOPLvW75cY

Thanks for your comment. I saw the case that you mentioned and I knew AnyLogic support 3D simulations. But the real question is, how to create it? In the tutorials I have browsed, the simulation environment is created in a 2D environment. Although it is possible to change the Z height of 2D wall elements and create a 3D window to convert 2D elements to 3D, it seems that it is hard to directly set operations such as a 3D vertical patch being a wall surface in the 3D environment model, given that I currently have a 3D environment model?  Best wish.
